# I'm trying to run the code below, but I got an error message says that object 'delta' is not found. Do you know what is the problem?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the code below, but I got an error message says that object 'delta' is not found. Do you know what is the problem?

Here is the code:

```
library(KMsurv)
data()
data(burn)
burn
options(max.print=2772)


library(survival)
KM.fit<-survfit(Surv(time,delta)~type,conf.type="none",data=burn)
summary(KM.fit)
```

Here is the error message:

```
 KM.fit<-survfit(Surv(time,delta)~type,conf.type="none",data=burn)
```

> Error in Surv(time, delta) : object 'delta' not found

Answer (score 0):

The `burn` doesn't have the columns 'time', 'delta'

```
names(burn)
#[1] "Obs" "Z1"  "Z2"  "Z3"  "Z4"  "Z5"  "Z6"  "Z7"  "Z8"  "Z9"  "Z10" "Z11" "T1"  "D1"  "T2"  "D2"  "T3"  "D3"
```

If we provide the correct names, it should work i.e. consider checking the `lung` dataset

```
names(lung)
#[1] "inst"      "time"      "status"    "age"       "sex"       
#[6] "ph.ecog"   "ph.karno"  "pat.karno" "meal.cal"  "wt.loss"
```

and now apply the function

```
survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data=lung)
#Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ ph.ecog, data = lung)

#   1 observation deleted due to missingness 
#            n events median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL
#ph.ecog=0  63     37    394     348     574
#ph.ecog=1 113     82    306     268     429
#ph.ecog=2  50     44    199     156     288
#ph.ecog=3   1      1    118      NA      NA
```

Comment: I have modified that to KM.fit<-survfit(Surv(T3,Z1)~type,conf.type="none",data=burn) , then I got this error message:                                         
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'type' not found

Comment: @Dana `type` is not in the `colnames(burn)` you can only use colums that are present in the data